# Protected custom settings as a parameter in an @AuraEnabled method causes error

Tags: apex, managed-package

Given

Apex controller

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String saveAppSetting(AppSetting__c config)
{
    if (config == null) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(System.Label.NO_DATA);
    }

    // skipped for brevity
    return 'success';
}
```

Aura component helper

```
saveAppSetting: function(component) {
    const action = component.get("c.saveAppSetting");
    action.setParam("config", null);
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        const state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log("Success");
        } else {
            console.error("Error");
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

When I execute this in a scratch org with a namespace, everything is fine. When this code runs in a **subscriber org** inside an installed managed packed, this ends up with the following error:

[image]

It doesn't get to this `if (config == null)` line on server, so it must break during deserialization and this is out of developer reach. Has anyone had such issues and does anybody know how to address it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard workaround for this is to use a normal String parameter instead:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String saveAppSetting(String configJson)
  AppSetting__c config = (AppSetting__c)
    JSON.deserialize(configJson, AppSetting__c.class);
```

---

```
action.setParam("configJson", JSON.stringify(null)); // Or an Object
```

---

In the meantime, you might want to report the bug to Support. As far as I can tell, this should work, it's just a glitch in the platform.

Answer (score 1):

I think issue might be with namespace of object.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String saveAppSetting(namespace__AppSetting__c config)
```

Try by adding namespace in auraenabled parameters. I think fields are passed with namespace but if not Pass fields also with namespace from lightning component.